# Setting list size and append item upon user input

Tags: python

I want to prompt a user for the size of an array and for that array's elements.

Example:

```
 Enter size of list: 4
 Enter elements: "apple","banana","pear","pineapple"
```

Output:

```
['apple','banana','pear','pineapple']
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
listsize = int(input("Enter size of list: "))
readylist = []*listsize
uinput = input("enter item")
uinput = uinput.split(',')
readylist.append(uinput)

print(readylist)
```

I'm getting this instead:

```
[['apple','banana','pear','pineapple']]
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: why would you ask user for the length of list? This is prone to mistakes. Better to just ask for elements and count the amount yourself. Otherwise what will you do if user says it will input 4 elements and then lists only 2 of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple solution as per your request,

```
readylist = []
for _ in range(int(raw_input("Enter size of list:"))):
    uinput = raw_input("enter item:")
    readylist.append(uinput)
print(readylist)
>>>['apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'orange']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your list to restricted, What you need is `collection.deque`

```
>>>listsize = int(input("Enter size of list: "))
>>>uinput = input("enter item")
>>>uinput = uinput.split(',')
>>>readylist  = collections.deque(uinput, listsize)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
uinput = input("enter items")
uinput = uinput.split(',')

print(uinput)
```

But if you want to ask multiple times and append to an existing list:

```
prev_inputs += uinput
```

Where `prev_inputs` is an already existing list